# writing an unique php function to be used on my website

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return, echo

I'm using a custom php code to translate my date format on my wordpress website, using get_the_time.
I have to use this code on various spaces on my website, sometimes more than one time on a page.

here is my code I'm adding inside my custom page templates when needed :

```
<?php 
$date  =  get_the_time('l j F Y');
$interdit = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$replace   = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado","Domingo", "Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

$date_espagnole = str_replace($interdit, $replace, $date);
echo ($date_espagnole);
?>
```

what I want to know is how can I only declare this code once, maybe in my function.php, and then just add this code when needed : `<?php echo ($date_espagnole);?>`

Here is what I've tried in my function.php :

```
function date_translation(){
$date  =  get_the_time('l j F Y');
$interdit = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$replace   = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado","Domingo", "Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

$date_espagnole = str_replace($interdit, $replace, $date);
return $date_espagnole;
}
```

and then in my custom pages when needed : `<?php date_translation();?>`

but it's not working. Is it possible to do this ? and if yes, what am I doing wrong ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Do you want to translate the current time? Or are you trying to replace instances of `the_date()` with your translated version?

Comment: well I'm trying to translate months and days, but that's not the main purpose of my question. I had to write this custom code, because I have troubles with a plugin with translation. So what I'm trying to do is to keep this code, but apply it in various places on my website. so the question is how can I create a function in my function.php, and then just echo the function on my pages. it could be a different code than the one I took as an example. do you understand what I mean ? thanks @mevius

Comment: Simply create function in your current theme's functions.php, and use them whereever you want to use. have you added your function in functions.php?

Comment: thanks @KaushaMehta, I did, but it's not working, I can't find what I am doing wrong... can you help ?

Comment: In your template: `<?php echo date_translation();?>`. You've forgotten an `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `return`ing `$date_espagnole`...not `echo`ing it. In order for the value to show up in your template, you need to echo it:

```
<?php echo date_translation();?>
```

Comment: thanks @mevius, works perfectly, I was really close ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To get the date in localized format, use `date_i18n()` ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n)). Here's a reusable function:

```
function so26817260_date( $date ) {
    return date_i18n( 'l j F Y',  strtotime( $date ) );
}

// usage: echo so26817260_date( get_the_time( 'l j F Y' ) );
```

Comment: thanks @diggy, I know how to get the date, that's not the problem... I really need to keep my custom code. would be to long to explain. The main purpose of my question, is how to only write it once (in my function.php I presume), and then use it on various places just with one php command

Comment: Your second block of code looks ok I guess, just need to `echo` when you use it. Remember that `get_the_time` returns the time of the current post and must be used in the loop.